# Brownian Motion/Wiener Process Probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Consider a standard Brownian motion/Wiener process $B_t$ with mean $0$
>   and variance $1$. Find $P(B_t<0$ for all $1\leq t \leq10)$.

My intuition tells me that this is a non-zero probability, but my (probably wrong) attempt shows otherwise. If someone can tell me where I messed up that would be great.

Attempt:

$$P(B_t<0 \text{ for all } 1 \leq t \leq10)=1-P(B_t>0 \text{ for some } 1 \leq t \leq10)$$
$$=1-P(B_t>0 \text{ for some } 0 \leq t \leq 9)$$

Since the probability density function for such processes is normal for some fixed time $t$, we have that the density function is $$f_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp\big(-\frac{x^2}{2t}\big)$$

Then by the [Reflection Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)#:~:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20probability,path%20about%20the%20value%20a.),

$$1-P(B_t>0 \text{ for some } 0 \leq t \leq 9)=1-2P(B_9>0)=1-2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{18\pi}\exp\big(-\frac{x^2}{18})dx$$

According to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2Fsqrt%2818pi%29exp%28%28-x%5E2%29%2F18%29dx%20from%200%20to%20infinity), the integral is $\frac{1}{2}$ which makes sense as the distribution of $B_t$ for any $t$ is normal with mean 0, thus the probability in question is $1-1=0$. If this isn't correct, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the second equality from the start of your attempt is true?

Comment: I thought that any segment of $B_t$ has the same distribution as long as they are equal size in $t$. I suppose this is not true?

Comment: **Increments** of $B_t$ of the same size have the same distribution. An easy way to see the difference is that standard Brownian motion satisfies $B_0 = 0$ but $B_1 \neq 0$ a.s. so it can't be the case that the segment of $B_t$ on $[0,1)$ has equal distribution to the segment on $[1,2)$. The difference with increments is that when considering an increment $B_t - B_s$ you have recentered the process around $B_s$.